# How do I set the file type for a new file in Komodo Edit/IDE?

Tags: python, komodo

I just downloaded komodo edit for editing python and I have an issue with its configuration. How would I get the editor to automatically assume that the code I type will be python. The highlighting of code parts only comes after i've typed the whole code and then saved adding the `.py` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the file type/language when you create a new file in Komodo. Instead of selecting File/New/New File, use File/New/File from Template, and choose Python (for 2.x) or Python3 from the dialog. The file type will take effect immediately for syntax highlighting and checking.

After you do this for the first time, you'll notice Python or Python3 appearing in the numbered list in the submenu under File/New, along with any other languages you've used recently.

If you're already editing a file and want to change its type without saving, you can use Edit/Current File Settings, and in the File Preferences panel change the Language selection. This may be useful, for example, if you need to switch a file from Python to Python3 or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Also, after launching new file, you can change the language from the lower portion of the Komodo Edit main window. You don't have to save as .py file.